# dbf get bold string values from the dbf file

Tags: text, vb6, dbf, printers, bold

I have an old software in vb6 using dbf files. However I don't have access to the code of the application, only the .exe. This software is in use to create labels and I must change the printed text to a bold one. Is there any solution to format the text in the dbf file and get it bold on my label?

Comment: Is the formatting done in VB6 code? Or does the DBF contain information which describes how the formatting should look?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution through the code, the formatting has been done in the VB6 code. The project was in an old desktop. Thank you.